# Customizing the Resources directory of an .app bundle with Javapackager

Tags: java, macos, deployment, dmg, javapackager

On macOS, I am using *Javapackager* to make an `Application.app` bundle (called a *disk image*) from my `Application.jar` Java archive:

```
javapackager \
  -deploy \
  -native image \
  -srcfiles Application.jar \
  -outdir dist \
  -outfile Application \
  -appclass Application
```

The resulting `Application.app` bundle is a *directory* with the following layout:

```
Application.app
|--Contents
   |--Info.plist
   |--PkgInfo
   |--Java
   |  |--Application.jar
   |--MacOS
   |  |--Application
   |--Resources
```

However I have some `<language>.lproj` directories (which hold `InfoPlist.strings` files for localizing some strings of the `Info.plist` file, cf. Apple's Developer [website](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)) on my file system that need to be copied in the `Resources` directory of the `Application.app` layout, like this:

```
Application.app
|--Contents
   |--Info.plist
   |--PkgInfo
   |--Java
   |  |--Application.jar
   |--MacOS
   |  |--Application
   |--Resources
      |--en.lproj
         |--InfoPlist.strings
      |--fr.lproj
         |--InfoPlist.strings
```

**How can I tell *Javapackager* to do that?** (I do not want to copy the `<language>.lproj` directories myself in the `Application.app` bundle after its creation, as it would break its signature.)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround:

1. put your custom `Info.plist` file in `package/macosx/` (create if non existent) for javapackager to pick it up during execution, then run your javapackager as you normally would.
2. manually copy the `*.lproj/InfoPlist.strings` structure over to the `Application.app/Contents/Resources` folder.
3. sign both files, replace with your values. Hint: You can find out your values from the javapackager console output. Something like:

   `codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Your Company Inc (A1234ABCDE)" --prefix com.domain. ./Application.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`

   do the same for `fr.lproj`
4. To verify it looks okay:

   `codesign --verify --strict --verbose=2 ./Application.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings`

   Should output:

   `./Application.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings: valid on disk` 
   `./Application.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings: satisfies its Designated Requirement`

   do the same for `fr.lproj`
5. Then replace existing signature with command below. This regenerates a new updated `CodeResources` file under `Contents/_CodeSignature/`

   `codesign -s "Developer ID Application: Your Company Inc (A1234ABCDE)" --prefix com.domain. --force --deep ./Application.app`

   Should output:

   `./Application.app: replacing existing signature`

   And the updated CodeResources file should have entries for `en.lproj` and `fr.lproj`like:

   ```
   <key>Resources/en.lproj/InfoPlist.strings</key>
   <dict>
       <key>hash</key>
       <data>
       CUsP4OMChUrxMRr6uFtSA7pFejs=
       </data>
       <key>optional</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   ```
6. Verify that your app conforms to Gatekeeper policies when you distribute with Developer ID, to mimic what Gatekeeper does.

   `codesign --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 ./Application.app`
7. Automate the steps above in a script!

Answer (score 0):

If you use (or can use) **maven**, you can do it with the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly).

First of all, you can use the [exec plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to perform the `jlink`/`javapackage` steps and on completion (in the `package` phase), copy your missing information to the destination folder.

Maven automatizes it for you and you don't have to perform manually those steps.

For instance:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
          </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
         <executable>jlink</executable>
         <!-- optional -->
         <workingDirectory>/tmp</workingDirectory>
         <arguments>
           <argument>--compress=2</argument>
           <argument>--strip-debug</argument>
           ...
         </arguments>
        [...]

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/copy-resources.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
</project>
```